# Is jQuery more compatible than Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing some research on the compatibility of jQuery and was wondering does it support more devices and browsers than plain Javascript or is it rather similar?

Comment: yes it is more compatible than javascript

Comment: jQuery is nothing but JavaScript

Comment: jQuery is a library of JavaScript, there are lot of them out there...

Comment: i think take down the question fast, its almost not a right question...

Comment: It's literally impossible for a library built on a language to be more compatible than the language itself. It makes it easier to handle all the different cases that you might otherwise have to code yourself, but in technical terms: jQuery cannot logically be more "compatible" than the language it's written in.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers support javascript.

Some browsers support some versions of jquery.

[jquery browser support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)